# Embedding Build information in debian package

Tags: debian, debian-packaging

I am building a debian package for an internal project.

I want to include information like **git remote** and **git rev-parse HEAD** in the debian package I build.

I also want to capture additional metadata like JIRA url etc.

What is correct way to do it. For now I copy output of those commands and save it in the file GIT-VERSION and package this file.

Comment: At this level of abstraction, this seems rather broad. The Debian changelog `/usr/share/doc/changelog.gz` seems like a natural place for this information.

Comment: ok. and merely capture the git sha and repo url ?
My problem is that users are building it from their fork. (atleast for now)

Comment: The Changelog is not machine-readable but it is a reasonably standard place for this type of information. If you need to be able to parse it, perhaps a dedicated file is the way to go.